# How can I make SublimeText to support ES6 syntax so I can search for functions?

Tags: sublimetext3

If I define a JavaScript function like this on a React component, Sublime Text 3 will next recognize it if I search for functions with the appropriate command (`cmd R` on a Mac)

```
foo = () =>{

}
```

I am defining it that way because it preserves type safety in TypeScript if I do, for example

```
   foo = (event: Event) => {

   }
```

Is there a way to support this style syntax for Sublime Text 3 (for example, by altering a configuration file or something else)? I tried a Babel javascript plugin and it didn't help, open to any type of solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest [public build](https://sublimetext.com/3), #3114, supports this functionality, so you can simply upgrade your old version.

[image]

Alternatively, you update the [JavaScript](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/JavaScript) package. Clone the entire `sublimehq/Packages` repository, then either copy or link the `JavaScript directory to Sublime's`Packages` directory:

- Windows Regular Install: `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages`
- Windows Portable Install: `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages`
- OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages`
- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages`

Many changes have been made to the JavaScript language definition over the past few months, including some after Build 3114 was released, so it will be well worth the time to upgrade.

Comment: I'm using Build 3114 and it doesn't support it, or I'm not doing something correctly (which you probably would have noticed in the OP if that's the case).  Maybe simply updating to 3114 isn't enough?

Comment: @Leahcim if you copy the code in my image above, do you get both `foo` and `bar` in the Cmd-R menu?

Comment: ok, I only get them in the Cmd-R menu if they're not defined as methods on a React component, so it seems like it's a React/Sublime issue, not a Sublime vanilla JavaScript/TypeScript issue.

Comment: @Leahcim I haven't used React before, so can you edit your original post and show examples of a function that doesn't show up and a function that does?

Comment: unfortunately, it turns out that SublimeText3 is not at all consistent here (it might be the fault of a plugin I have). For example, in one file I have two render methods with the exact same signature `render(){}`but it only appears once in Cmd-R menu, however, in another file, I have the same thing and render appears twice in the Cmd-R menu.

Comment: @Leahcim please work up a [mcve] and post an issue [here](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues). Try running it both with your normal plugins, and with all plugins disabled, so we can figure out where exactly the problem lies. Most likely it has to do with different function signatures between the different `render()` functions in the two files.